# Is there another way to write the product $ 2^2\times 3^2\times 4^2\times 5^2\times 6^2\times \cdots =(n^2)!\;$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial

I have this product

$$ 2^2\times 3^2\times 4^2\times 5^2\times 6^2\times \cdots =(n^2)!$$

Can we write this in another way?

Thank you

Comment: That's two ways already. How many do you need?!

Comment: What about $(n!)^2$?

Comment: only one please I have no Idea (please give me +1 I'm new )

Comment: Is there a specific form you want that fulfills a certain requirement?

Comment: i want to write it if possible in relation with $n!$

Comment: Just "factorize" the square to the whole expression $2^2\times 3^2\times 4^2\times\cdots\times n^2=(2\times 3\times 4\times\cdots\times n)^2=(n!)^2$.

Comment: Ah so $(n^2)!=(n!)^2$

Comment: No $(n^2)!=2\times 3\times\cdots\times n^2$ there are terms $(n+1)(n+2)\cdots n^2$ in surplus.

Comment: @NoraNour $(n^2)!\neq (n!)^2$, you have $(n^2)!=1\cdot 2 \cdots (n^2-1)\cdot n^2$ but $ (n!)^2=(1\cdot 2\cdots(n-1)\cdot n)^2=1^2\cdot 2^2 \cdots (n-1)^2\cdot n^2$

Comment: You can also write $$\prod_{k=1}^n k^2$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not $(n^2)!$, it is $(n!)^2$.

(For example, if $n=3$ then $(n^2)!$ is $(3^2)!=9!=362880$ whereas $(n!)^2=(3!)^2=6^2=36$.)

Comment: are you sure ? why ?

Comment: @NoraNour Take as an example $n=10$. The left hand side is $2^2\times 3^2 \times \cdots \times 10^2$, while $(n^2)! = 100! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times \cdots  \times 100$. These cannot be equal as they do not have the same prime factors. For instance, $100!$ is divisible by $11$ while $2^2 \times 3^2 \times \cdots \times 10^2$ is not.

Comment: but I have $2^2\times 3^2\times 4^2\times 5^2\times $ not (2\times3\times4\times5\ldots)^2$

Comment: @NoraNour they are the same thing: $(2\times 2)\times (3\times 3)=(2\times 3)\times (2\times 3)$, etc. Having $(n^2)!$ would mean the *number* of terms, rather than the terms themselves, gets squared.

Comment: @NoraNour  What you wrote would mean $$(n^2)! = (n^2 \cdot (n^2-1) \cdot (n^2-2)\cdot \cdots \cdot 2 \cdot 1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Well in product notation it is $$\prod_{k=1}^n k^2$$, but realistically $(n!) ^2$ is much better notation.